# Vacuum chamber incident during apollo preparation

Tags: history, vacuum

I've heard of an incident in the mid 60s: someone was testing a space suit in an vacuum chamber, the suit depressurized and the man fainted after feeling the water in his mouth begin to boil.

It's a good story but I am wondering : does that really happened ?

A quick search in the nasa website didn't gave me anything (maybe i was just using the wrongs key-words)

Does such a story ring a bell to anyone ?

Comment: http://www.spacesafetymagazine.com/aerospace-engineering/space-suit-design/early-spacesuit-vacuum-test-wrong/ , I suppose. (Not sure if credible enough reference for what are you looking for.)

Comment: It really happened and @Martin has provided a link to the story.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers ! I did see this but I didn't know if it was to be trusted as it was the only reference I could find... I would have expected someone else to have published something.

Comment: It's at least referred to in the NASA Engineering and Safety Center presentation here https://nescacademy.nasa.gov/video/481016c7afb6478c8405a7fdac7f84ce1d See the slide displayed at 22:25 into the video. The website stupidly wants you to log in to download the slides, even though you can see them in the video without logging in.

Comment: Thank you very much ! This is perfect !

Comment: Actual footage and audio from the incident included in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHNtsOvQryU